# What could cause a deserialization in a deployed service to fail while it succeeds localy?

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

I added a second method to my WCF service. It essentially does the same job as the other one except that it receives an xml document, deserialise it, and call the other method. It works perfectly locally, my XML is deserialized and the call succeeds. However, now that I have deployed it on my on-premise server, the call returns a 500 error because the deserialization failed.

My XML document has namespaces associated with every node, the root, and sub-root element have the "ns1" et all the others "ns2" prefix. To do the deserialization I (for now at least) hardcoded the namespaces for each node.

The troncated xml document:

```xml
<ns1:ValiderEtEnrichirGlobalEchangePartage
    xmlns:ns1="API:WebApi"
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.ra.fr/API/Transport/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ns1:messageGlobal>
        <ns0:AuteurEchange>...</ns0:AuteurEchange>
        <ns0:Documents>
            <ns0:DocumentEchangePartage>...</ns0:DocumentEchangePartage>
        </ns0:Documents>
        <ns0:ExpediteurEchange>...</ns0:ExpediteurEchange>
    </ns1:messageGlobal>
</ns1:ValiderEtEnrichirGlobalEchangePartage>
```

The deserialising process in the service's method:

```cs
public GlobalEchangePartageValide ValiderEtEnrichirGlobalEchangePartageXML(string xmlMessageGlobal)
{

    XmlRootAttribute xroot = new XmlRootAttribute();
    xroot.ElementName="ValiderEtEnrichirGlobalEchangePartage";
    xroot.Namespace="API:WebApi";

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ValiderEtEnrichirGlobalEchangePartage),xroot );
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlMessageGlobal);
    ValiderEtEnrichirGlobalEchangePartage messageGlobal = (ValiderEtEnrichirGlobalEchangePartage)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);

    return ValiderEtEnrichirGlobalEchangePartage(messageGlobal.GlobalEchangePartage);
}
```

The class coresponding to the xml root element:

```cs
[XmlRootAttribute("ValiderEtEnrichirGlobalEchangePartage")]
public class ValiderEtEnrichirGlobalEchangePartage
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName=("messageGlobal"))]
    public GlobalEchangePartage GlobalEchangePartage { get; set; }
}
```

The class of xml sub root element:

```cs
[DataContract(Namespace = NamespacesConstantes.NAMESPACE_TRANSPORT)]
public class GlobalEchangePartage
{

    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = ("AuteurEchange"), Namespace = "http://www.ra.fr/API/Transport/")]
    public Auteur AuteurEchange { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = ("ExpediteurEchange"), Namespace = "http://www.ra.fr/API/Transport/")]
    public Auteur ExpediteurEchange { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [XmlArray(ElementName="Documents", Namespace = "http://www.ra.fr/API/Transport/")]
    [XmlArrayItem("DocumentEchangePartage")]
    public List<DocumentEchangePartage> Documents { get; set; }

}
```

The error I get is in French very ambiguous but can be approximatively translated by :

```
WCF error : System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException: The formatting module generated an exception when trying to deserialize the 
message: an error occurred when trying to deserialize the 
API:WebApi:xmlMessageGlobal parameter. The InnerException message was 'An 
error occurred when deserializing the System.String object.   Ending (TN : 
last /final ) element 'xmlMessageGlobal' from the namespace 'API:WebApi' 
expected. Found element 'ns1:ValiderEtEnrichirGlobalEchangePartage' from the 
namespace "API:WebApi'.
```

Original :

```
WCF error : System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException: Le 
module de formatage a généré une exception en tentant de désérialiser le
message : Une erreur s'est produite en tentant de désérialiser le paramètre
API:WebApi:xmlMessageGlobal. Le message InnerException était 'Une
erreur   s'est produite lors de la désérialisation de l'objet de type
System.String.   Élément de fin 'xmlMessageGlobal' provenant de l'espace de 
noms 'API:WebApi' attendu. Trouvé élément
'ns1:ValiderEtEnrichirGlobalEchangePartage' provenant de l'espace de noms 
'API:WebApi'.'.
```

Notice how it says that 'xmlMessageGlobal' is expected  in the XML document while it is the variable's name ...

Thanks (for reading) a lot !

PS : If the French error message could be put in something that collapses it, I would appreciate, i didn't find a way to do it.

Comment: Why do you have [XmlRoot] on GlobalEchangePartage ?  It seems at least superfluous.

Comment: I changed it thanks ! ( Doesn't change anything)

Comment: Check your encoding headers in the web request

Comment: @AEonAX The web request is done through Microsoft Azure Logic Apps, and I believed it sends everythings in UTF-8. I'm not sure i can check the request's headers.

Comment: Well, the local vs deployed differences are very strange. We are talking about the exact same code, right? That leaves the OS (version), culture settings, other configurations...  WCF uses Web.Config at different places. And Machine.config .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem encountered was indeed a deserialization problem. However, it wasn't about the piece of code I had written, it was when the string parameter was beeing received. Because my xml doc was an wrapped in another xml document (the request) there was issues in the processing. By base64 encoding my XML in my Logic App, and decoding it in the service i was able to fix the deserialization issue.

TLDR : be careful when you send xml through a String parameter.